# Find the basis of the Null space and the column space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ 3x3 matrix has eigenvectors $u,w,z$ and eigenvalues $0,2,3$ respectively. Find a basis for the nullspace and column space.Solve $Ax=w+z$. Prove that $Ax=u$ does not have any solution.

Sol:

$Au=0 ,Aw=2w, Az=3z $ and $A$ will have 3,2,0 in its diagonal and zero elsewhere. so Nullspace dimension= 1 and column dim=2. Basis for the column space is the (3,0,0) and (0,2,0). And a basis for Nullspace is the vector $u$ But I can't find it. So far so good?? Or I made a mistake somewhere?
For the other 2 questions I can multiply the eq with $A$ and get $$A^2x=2w+3z$$ and for the last one $$A^2x=0$$

Comment: Surely you are missing a great deal of information in the problem statement.... for example, what is $A$?  A matrix I assume, but of what dimension?  If $A$ is a $100\times 100$ matrix for example, then it is hopeless to try to find the nullspace or rowspace with the information provided and $Ax=u$ could have a solution.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry its a 3x3 matrix

Comment: Are you sure you want to find the basis for the row space and not the column space?  "*A will have 3,2,0 in its diagonal and zero elsewhere*" This is false, there are many more possibilities than just $A$ being a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @JMoravitz i meatn collumn!! Isnt A diagonizable?

Comment: Diagonali**zable** not not necessarily Diago**nal**.  There is a big difference between these terms.

Comment: @JMoravitz 3x3 with 3 distinct eigenvalues wont give me a diagonal matrix?

Comment: No, of course not.  For smaller example, consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ which is a $2\times 2$ matrix with two distinct eigenvalues, namely $0$ and $2$ with eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ respectively and although this matrix is diagonalizable, it is certainly not diagonal.  $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Au=0$, $Aw=2w$ and $Az=3z$ by definition, you know that $2w$ and $3z$ belong to the column space of $A$, so $w$ and $z$ do as well. Since $\{w,z\}$ is a linearly independent set, you know that the column space has dimension at least $2$.

Moreover $u$ belongs to the null space, therefore the null space has dimension at least $1$. Since $3=1+2$, the rank-nullity theorem says that

- the dimension of the null space is $1$;
- the dimension of the column space is $2$.

A basis for the former is $\{u\}$; a basis for the latter is $\{w,z\}$.

How can we solve $Ax=w+z$? Since $A$ is diagonalizable, having three distinct eigenvalues, we have $x=\alpha u+\beta w+\gamma z$; then
$$
Ax=\alpha Au+\beta Aw+\gamma Az=2\beta w+3\gamma z
$$
so the equality
$$
2\beta w+3\gamma z=w+z
$$
implies $\beta=1/2$ and $\gamma=1/3$. You can choose $\alpha$ without restrictions.

Can you finish the $Ax=u$ part?

Comment: why w,z  is linearly independent. and from which definition they belong in the column! ??

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis The column space consists of all vectors of the form $Av$, for $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Suppose otherwise, then $z=\alpha w$ for some constant $\alpha$.  Then we would have $Az=3z$ since $z$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $3$, but we would also have $Az=A(\alpha w)=\alpha Aw = \alpha 2w = 2(\alpha w) = 2z$ at the same time

Comment: perfect thank you!!!

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis It's an important fact that eigenvectors relative to distinct eigenvalues form a linearly independent set.

Comment: I did the last part . since u,w,z indepentent form a basis for $ R^3$ so x=au+bz+gw and suppose x is a sollution Ax=u. then u is a linear combination of z and w . which is impossible.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis That's correct.